# How to hide drop down button when no hover in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I have facing the issue with flutter web.

The menu appears when there is a hover.

But when there is no hover, the menu does not hide.

```
 TextButton(
          key: formKey,
          onPressed: () {},
          onHover: (a) {

           // showMenus(context);
           // if (isShow == false) {
           // dropdown.unfocus();
           // }


            // isShow ? showMenus(context) : dropdown.unfocus();

                 if (isShow) {
                   showMenus(context);
        
                 } else {
                   Navigator.pop(context);
                 }
          },
          child: Text("Hover"),),
```

Comment: Why don't you add your code? You need to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: same issue i have facing